# Show Excel Cell Only If Another Has Data

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function, spreadsheet, cell-format

I am trying to format the below Excel sheet so that when a date is entered into cell J1, cells G24 - G37 populate with a date a specific to what I need. I currently have the cells formatted as follows: `=SUM(J1-14)`, adjusted according to the needs of each cell.

Is there a way for me to format these cells so data only appears if a date is entered into J1 instead of the never-ending # it currently shows?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Wrap the J1-14 formula within IF statement in cell G24 and respectively thru G37. Formula  =IF(ISBLANK(J1),"",J1-14) Note that you would still get all # if the input value entered in J1 results into a negative number/date in G24, just in case